# C# windows application (winform) how to display console on different thread, and close separately

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, console

in a windows application, I want the ability to bring up a console, which might or might not display data from the application itself, but might also be used for entering in extra info, or changing values without the need for app itself (this is 50% utility 50% debug)

**now some of the issues I have arrived at**

- closing the console closes the app
- if the console is running something (waiting for a prompt) the window cannot run
- same thing for the window running, if its running console can't run

here is the bit of code dealing with the console

```
namespace Kproject
{

public partial class KGUI : Form
{
    public KGUI()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool AllocConsole();

    private void Form_Keypress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyChar)
        {
            case 'c':
                AllocConsole();
                ConsoleCode();
                break;
            case 'b':
                Console.Beep(2000, 100);
                break;
            case 'v':
                string s = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine(s);
                break;
            default:
                Console.Beep(6000, 50);
                break;
        }
    }
    private void ConsoleCode()
    {
        string s = "";
        while(s != "exit"){
            s = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (s)
            {
                case "c1":
                    /*
                     * do task
                     */
                    break;
                case "c2":
                    /*
                     * do task
                     */
                    break;
                case "c3":
                    /*
                     * do task
                     */
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.Beep(100, 300);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

hitting c will raise the console, and will block app usage until exit has been typed, what I would like is for it to just sit quietly in the back until it is needed, or for it to be closed without need to close the entire program

how can I run a console without it conflicting with the app and resolve the issues noted before.

Comment: Okay, you forgot to ask a question though...

Comment: You're probably much better off not using the actual console, but rather creating a new form that just has nothing but a textbox on it (possibly one for displaying output and one for input) that you use in place of a console.

Comment: While I certainly have considered going that route (and am currently coding up a new form that might end up serving that purpose) I still believe that there has to be a way in which to run strait from the console.